# Sentry Docker Port 80

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sentry

I'm using Sentry via Docker-Compose. My Docker Compose file has 3 services:

- sentry
- sentry-cron
- sentry-worker-1

Only the sentry service exposes port 9000. Now I want to map the container port 9000 to port 80 on my local machine. I do write 80:9000 and application runs with all the components and workers, but when I go to Admin Panel -> Buffer, the application crashes coz it redirects it to port 9000 where no service is listening.

Any solution for this?
Thanks